# Not able to uploading csv file to azure storage blob

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

Below code is not uploading the sample MY_TEST_FILE.csv to azure storage blob. Not able to figure the issue or find any examples for doing so. anything missing in the code? No errors in the log & file is not found in azure storage

'''

```
        StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("test", "test");
        String uri = "https://test.blob.core.windows.net";

        BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(uri)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();
        CamelContext mycontext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        mycontext.getRegistry().bind("client", client);
       
        mycontext.setStreamCaching(true);
        mycontext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
              

                from("file:c://folder2?fileName=MY_TEST_FILE.csv&noop=true").to("azure-storage-blob://test/report?blobName=MY_TEST_FILE.csv&operation=uploadBlockBlob&serviceClient=#client");


            }
        });
        mycontext.start();'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to provide credentials for the azure-storage-blob component.

```java
StorageSharedKeyCredential credentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
mycontext.getRegistry().bind("credentials", credentials);

from("file:c://folder2?fileName=MY_TEST_FILE.csv&noop=true")
    .to("azure-storage-blob:accountName/containerName?"
         + "blobName=MY_TEST_FILE.csv&operation=uploadBlockBlob"
         + "&credentials=#credentials");
```

Note that `#beanId` is [deprecated](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-ReferringbeansfromEndpointURIs) and you might have to switch to `#bean:beanId` depending on camel version.

Comment: Still didn't work. I can see below error in the log file java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
 at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31)

Comment: What version of camel are you using? Older camel versions use Azure SDK version 8 and newer ones use SDK 12 which can lead to some differences. You can also try without defining with serviceClient which I guess is used for more [advanced](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/azure-storage-blob-component.html#_advanced_azure_storage_blob_configuration) configurations.

Comment: Also it's preferable that you add new information like logs to your original question instead cramming them in to the comments.

Comment: Issue got fixed after running the same code in spring application. Running Standalone  class caused issue

Comment: Yeah for standalone camel applications its generally recommended to use either camel main class or framework like spring. There are plenty of maven archetypes for both making them pretty easy to setup.